# New Field on InfoPath 2010 form not being picked up by workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I looked, but don't think this has been answered.

I have an existing InfoPath form to which I am adding one `TextBox` control. I've named the field [ChargeCode] and created a column in my List (and library) also named [ChargeCode]. The form serves a "Drop Off Library".

There is a workflow which looks like:

1. User submits the form.
2. Form is momentarily saved in the Drop Off Library.
3. Workflow copies the item to a List and deletes the original library item.

However, when the Workflow copies the form into the List, my new field's data is not there.

Any ideas what is causing this? Do I need to map the new field somehow?

Comment: Pause the workflow and make sure the data is actually getting into the drop off library.

Comment: I can see the Charge Code for a moment in the library before the workflow runs. I just don't understand why it's not being transferred into the list.

Comment: Just open the workflow, make some change, then save and publish.

Comment: Yes, but the key is which change...

Comment: Just make any change, and then undo your change. What I want you to try is to save and publish. I hope this will resolve the current issue.

Comment: I've published several times, but I always created the columns on the SharePoint web interface. Just now I tried doing everything in SPD...and voila...it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Previously, I always created the columns on the SharePoint web interface. Just now I tried doing everything in SPD...and voila...it's working.

I added the field and control to my form using InfoPath Designer. Then, added the columns to both applicable list and library in SPD. Adjusted the workflow in SPD, and published. Tested my form and workflow by creating a test item and it retained the new field.

So not sure if I happen to do the steps in a different order or this just works better in SPD.

Answer (score 0):

After adding new fields. You should either close or refresh the SharePoint Designer Data.

So to fix this, you can close the designer and start it. Then publish the workflow.